# Smallest asymmetric cubic graphs

Tags: graph-theory

[Wikipedia states:](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frucht_graph)

> The Frucht graph is **one of the two** smallest cubic graphs possessing only a single graph automorphism, the identity (that is, every vertex can be distinguished topologically from every other vertex).

What exactly is meant by saying that there are two, and what is the other one?

I assume it doesn't simply mean that there are two non-isomorphic ones because with a small computational experiment, I seem to find 5 different asymmetric cubic graphs on 12 vertices. Of these 5, the last one is the Frucht graph.

[image]

In [graph6 notation](https://users.cecs.anu.edu.au/%7Ebdm/data/formats.html),

```
K?ABE`Ke@WEO
K?ABCfCU@WF?
K?ABAdgi?wQ_
K?AB?tos@WP_
K?`@EaKX?sEO
```

Comment: I don't know yet what's up with this either, but I've replicated your small computational experiment, and also got $5$ graphs; it's not just you.

Comment: @MishaLavrov Thanks for confirming that it's not a misunderstanding.

Comment: I have the book that Wikipedia cites at the office. I'll check it tomorrow.

Comment: As far as Wikipedia is concerned, it originally cited that book for the claim that the Frucht graph is the smallest such graph (but with no more explicit mention of uniqueness). [Some unidentified IP address in March 2011](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:Contributions/71.201.65.77) edited that article and several others to claim that it is one of *two* graphs.

Comment: @MishaLavrov Actually I managed to check the book, and that's exactly what it says: it's "the" smallest such graph. It doesn't mention two graphs. Page 112. Time to fix Wikipeida, I guess (all five of those pages—five is the magic number today)

Comment: Perhaps they were only considering the two planar ones? Good job on fixing the wikipedia page.

Comment: Nice, maybe you should refer to the specific revision of Wiki and an answer...